# .htaccess: не загружаются изображения

Tags: .htaccess

Доброго времени суток!

В файле .htaccess у меня написано следующее:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*)\/ http://mysite.ru/index.php?page=$1 [R,L]
```

Но при запросе изображения из `http://img.mysite.ru/fest_1/1.jpg` оно не грузится, т.к. URI режется и перебрасывает на `http://mysite.ru/index.php?page=fest_1`. Что нужно добавить в .htaccess, чтобы изображения загружались нормально?

Comment: Спасибо.Решил проблему сам.

Comment: @Glorymirror, По возможности публикуйте ответы на форуме, они могут помочь многим в будущем.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решилась добавлением строки `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s`, которая обнаруживает файл ненулевого размера.